# How can I send multiple value as request in axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have form text value in form state hooks While image in another state hooks During sending thee image and form text value I get the image validation error it means fd value is not passing as request

axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/store`,form,fd);

Comment: you can send as a object `{form:form, id: fd}`..

Comment: axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/store`,`{form:form,fd:fd}`);
not working

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: all lvalidaiton error value is not send as request

Comment: please go [link](https://github.com/axios/axios)  `Ctr+f` search..Performing a POST request... i think it's should work... maybe other code problem..

Comment: please share more code...

Comment: When i send one by one it works

Comment: your problem with form data not url ...

Comment: No bro form data is correct if send only one data in axios it works for both but i want to send image and form text at the same time

Comment: are you using laravel?

Comment: when you pass as object .. you need to get data request  `data.form.image & data.id`..